# Abstract class with a nested abstract generic function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a table that can change content and position of a special row. That row will be different for all pages.

Now I have an error `Generic type 'Table<SpecialFunctions>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)` when classes extend abstract Table class.

I've understood that in abstract class, child classes getSpecialFunctions() should return SpecialFunctions. How to make the getSpecialFunctions() to return a specific type for each child class?

```
abstract class Table<SpecialFunctions> {
  constructor() {}

  loadData() {}
  showTable() {}
  updateCell() {}

  abstract getSpecialFunctions(): SpecialFunctions;
}

class DoneWorksPageTable extends Table {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage{
    return {
      text: "test",
      addNewDoneWork: () => console.log("test done work class"),
    };
  }
}
class InformationPageTable extends Table {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage{
    return {
      toLoad: ["file", "table", "text", "image"],
      addNewInfo: () => console.log("test info class"),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't refer to private types/values like `IDoneWorksPageTableSpecialRow`, etc.  Either declare such types or, even better, replace them with native TypeScript types.  That way we can copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and the only problems present are the ones you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your `Table` class as generic, with a single type parameter named `SpecialFunctions`. This name - `SpecialFunctions` - acts here similarly to a parameter name in a function. You can choose whatever name you like - it brings meaning only to you as a coder. For the compiler, it could be named `T` and would work the same way.

Having said that, since your `Table` class requires a type parameter, you need to provide it wherever you use it - just as you would do it with a function call.

So you need to provide the required types in places where you extend the class:

```
interface TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage {}
interface TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage{}

abstract class Table<SpecialFunctions> {
  constructor() {}

  loadData() {}
  showTable() {}
  updateCell() {}

  abstract getSpecialFunctions(): SpecialFunctions;
}

class DoneWorksPageTable extends Table<TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage> {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage{
    return {
      text: "test",
      addNewDoneWork: () => console.log("test done work class"),
    };
  }
}
class InformationPageTable extends Table<TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage> {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage{
    return {
      toLoad: ["file", "table", "text", "image"],
      addNewInfo: () => console.log("test info class"),
    };
  }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEBiB7KAZWwWDgBsAlPAdwHkQARPECAdQIGsBnABTgDmKAN4BfAFChIsRCgzZ8REmSq0GASRAwCAWzhhgLfkLHjxcAEbcwURGGQJycbtzSXyEADzEIpCjgBXEAQDFm4APmRhcWQHMJsAkIIACgBKKIkY5HI8OAATRn04NIys7gALWlR3CBLTWIDMPP0IAGEIcnI6zNjLa1sQ5CEwHz9yQODQkG40gC5kUZUJkMNpgG5xTMdnV2ZWDigeYwhqiw9kCAAPSBA811OPT3lcAkWKanomFnYuPkEISLRWLDN7jIIrMJzNBYF5KXwqD4MPY-Q5-ExZWJQCBgAJQEBRDGxZCQa7zABEkGsZIANITenk8gA5CA0ZEHTjzEoAXkiCDCeA8ADocgJkhSINZkHlvsgaFwHE4XGTUrSichRBtYhIJNsXMhNNooHopscHigrjc7m4zl5nopQYiQAbdPpVsdAVkQcp-OCpjNUvM7a9vapPs6ja6jP8gUSsTi8QS1bEwHgADK5PLzADaZJgwA8NOQFJqhfF11LwD0QjJAF1VUn8kyWc7OekeXFpgKIMK8KLxZLQNoFTtlfWtZr1ZsgA) is a playground link.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you! Now I can create classes for each table on the site, with much less duplicate code :)

Answer (score 0):

I mean you haven't supplied the generics for your abstracts, as it says. And I'm sure the full error points to the lines where you extend your tables. In other words do:

```
class DoneWorksPageTable extends Table<TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage> {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnDoneWorksPage{
    return {
      text: "test",
      addNewDoneWork: () => console.log("test done work class"),
    };
  }
}
class InformationPageTable extends Table<TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage> {
  getSpecialFunctions(): TypeForSpecialRowOnInformationPage{
    return {
      toLoad: ["file", "table", "text", "image"],
      addNewInfo: () => console.log("test info class"),
    };
  }
}
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKqZBTAPAMoAOusAlsMgGICuAdvOQPb1gB8CA3gFAJKtIUWvGZQAFAEpuAXx58EyZsAAmAEWARgU2QrAALZgHdsIPDq5z+tYis24AwrmTILchaCFxEAc1wQSMkoaBiZBKQAuBECKKjpGCBY2AG4eOVhBREQAXm4Ffn4IXAAPCCiAIiLIcoAafILVFQA5XCM1VlwAdTEAayidbM4MtmY8ADolH3FK3EgEFQ6EI16kVHRyyTqChBlUnggAT1IECByTo9xmADMTvZQ0DHb6Lt6wAAVgP1M8BBKi+hUGG+BFOnF4-D8AVIsRCCSSYEiJ0Q4IKUH8tCg9Dy20KfwqVQgtXq-EaLTaHW6UD6CAGQ0Eo1wE2YUxmcwWzyWK3u6029V2Cjk6TWGAAkvQrmIALaaJIfL44XC-Uq4AFAhX4ITkeg+MEKSExYLxMJsRGa7XY1HozEIcoACWcSk5UGQKnKqX4gqAA